# How to move a TextView into the Toolbar through CoordinatorLayout?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-coordinatorlayout

I'm working on building a `coordinator layout` that is made up of a toolbar, a relative layout that is to hide on scroll, a layout that is static always above the `scrollable list`, and a `RecyclerView`.

I currently have it laid out as I want it to, as seen here:

- Green is the toolbar
- Orange is the relative layout to hide on scroll
- Red is my static layout that is to stay above the recycler view and
  move up but not hide.
- White is my RecyclerView

[image]

This next image is what it looks like once I scroll the whole way up the recycler view.

So my orange view hides as I want it to, which is perfect.  The only step i'm missing is moving the "Title 1" textview into becoming the title of the toolbar.  I've seen examples where they have done something kind of similar with an image, but haven't been able to duplicate it yet with a custom behavior.  I'm assuming thats what this will take?

Does anyone have any advice on if my layout needs to change to make this possible, and any advice for a custom behavior if that is what this will take?

[image]

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">
        <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
            android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap">
            <!-- HEADER -->
            <RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/rel1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                android:background="@color/lightGreen"
                android:layout_marginTop="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:paddingTop="10dp"
                android:paddingBottom="10dp">
                <TextView
                    android:id="@+id/title1"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:text="Resist the urge"
                    android:textSize="35sp"
                    android:includeFontPadding="true"
                    android:layout_centerInParent="true"/>

                <TextView
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_below="@id/resistUrgeTitleTextView"
                    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                    android:text="Use a method below to help."
                    android:includeFontPadding="true"/>
            </RelativeLayout>

            <FrameLayout
                android:id="@+id/main.framelayout.title"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="100dp"
                android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
                android:background="@color/lightOrange"
                android:orientation="vertical"
                app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                >

                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/main.linearlayout.title"
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="center"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    >

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:gravity="bottom|center"
                        android:text="Title 1"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:textSize="30sp"
                        app:layout_behavior="com.uhg.ent.mobile.quit4life.UrgeIntervention.TitleTextViewBehavior"
                        />

                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                        android:text="Subtitle"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        />

                </LinearLayout>
            </FrameLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                android:backgroundTint="@color/lightGreen"
                app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
                app:title=""/>
            <!--<TextView
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_gravity="center_vertical|center_horizontal"
                android:text="Resist the urge"
                android:textColor="@android:color/black"
                android:textSize="30sp"
                app:layout_behavior="com.uhg.ent.mobile.quit4life.UrgeIntervention.TitleTextViewBehavior"
                />-->


        </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
        <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
            android:id="@+id/cardConstraintLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
            android:background="@android:color/holo_red_dark"
            android:layout_marginTop="0dp">

            <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                android:id="@+id/pager"
                android:layout_width="0dp"
                android:layout_height="175dp"
                android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0"
                android:paddingBottom="50dp"/>
            <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="20dp"
                android:id="@+id/viewPagerIndicator"
                app:tabBackground="@drawable/pager_indicator_selector_gray"
                app:tabGravity="center"
                app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/interventionCategoryViewPager"
                android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>
        </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
        <!-- </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>-->
        <!--<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/main.toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
            app:layout_anchor="@id/main.framelayout.title"
            app:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark"
            app:title=""
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin">
        </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>-->
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>
    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/white"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
    </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
  </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

EDIT:

I've got a little bit of progress made.  I think I have the layout how I want, and i've got a behavior started.  I am able to move the TextView, but it is getting lost behind the toolbar.  I want it to go on top of the toolbar.  My goal is to move the title from the yellow block into the green block.

Do I need to adjust my layout so make it possible for the textview to appear on top of the title bar?

[image]

New code layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="60dp"
        android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
        android:backgroundTint="@color/lightOrange"
        app:title=""
        android:layout_marginTop="20dp"/>
    <android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@id/toolbar">
        <TextView
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
            android:gravity="bottom|center"
            android:text="Test 1"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="30sp"
            app:layout_behavior="com.uhg.ent.mobile.quit4life.UrgeIntervention.TitleTextViewBehavior"
            android:elevation="100dp"/>
        <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
            android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar">

            <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
                android:id="@+id/collapsing_toolbar"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed|snap">
                <LinearLayout
                    android:id="@+id/main.framelayout.title"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_gravity="bottom|center_horizontal"
                    android:background="@color/lightGreen"
                    android:orientation="vertical"
                    app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"
                    android:paddingTop="50dp">
                    <!--<TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:gravity="bottom|center"
                        android:text="Resist The Urge"
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:textSize="30sp"
                        app:layout_behavior="com.uhg.ent.mobile.quit4life.UrgeIntervention.TitleTextViewBehavior"
                        android:paddingTop="20dp"/>-->
                    <TextView
                        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
                        android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
                        android:text="Test 2."
                        android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                        android:paddingBottom="20dp"
                        />
                </LinearLayout>
            </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>
            <android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
                android:id="@+id/cardConstraintLayout"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"

                android:layout_marginTop="0dp">

                <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
                    android:id="@+id/viewPager"
                    android:layout_width="0dp"
                    android:layout_height="175dp"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0"
                    android:paddingBottom="50dp"/>
                <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
                    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                    android:layout_height="20dp"
                    android:id="@+id/viewPagerIndicator"
                    app:tabBackground="@drawable/pager_indicator_selector_gray"
                    app:tabGravity="center"
                    app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
                    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
                    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/interventionCategoryViewPager"
                    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"/>
            </android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
        </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

        <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
            android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent"
            android:background="@android:color/white"
            app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">
        </android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView>
    </android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: https://github.com/adeelturk/Collapsing-Tool-viewpager-and-tabs

Its a sample code i have ui thinsed a toolbar view pager and view pager contains a fragmnets each fragment have a recyclerview

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> My goal is to move the title from the yellow block into the green
>   block.

As your goal is to set the Title from the yellow block into the green there is no need to move `Textview` in yellow block you can set Title in yellow block with **`setTitle`** property of Toolbar.

**`setCollapseMode`** with `Toolbar` you can set it to **`COLLAPSE_MODE_OFF/COLLAPSE_MODE_PARALLAX/COLLAPSE_MODE_PIN`**

[More Detail on CollapseMode](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/design/widget/CollapsingToolbarLayout.LayoutParams.html)

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:layout_collapseMode="pin" /> // to  pin in place until it reaches the bottom of the layout
```

---

Implement **AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener** listener on your **AppBarLayout** to determine the **`CollpasingToolbar`** is collapsed or not and set Title in the **`Toolbar`** accordingly.

Call below method on `OnCreate()` of `Activity`.

```
 private void setTitleOfLayout() {
        AppBarLayout appBarLayout = findViewById(R.id.appbar_layout);
        appBarLayout.addOnOffsetChangedListener(new AppBarLayout.OnOffsetChangedListener() {
            boolean isShow;
            int scrollRange = -1;

            @Override
            public void onOffsetChanged(AppBarLayout appBarLayout, int verticalOffset) {
                if (scrollRange == -1) {
                    scrollRange = appBarLayout.getTotalScrollRange();
                }
                if (scrollRange + verticalOffset == 0) {

                  // orange part is not visible so set The title 

                    if (myTitleName != null)
                        toolbar.setTitle(myTitleName);

                    isShow = true;
                } else if (isShow) {
                     // orange part is visible so remove the title with

                      space here make sure your are not setting null in toolbar.

                    toolbar.setTitle(" ");

                    isShow = false;
                }
            }
        });

    }
```

Comment: I think this could work as a back up plan, but my ideal scenario is to actually have the title animate itself moving from one block into the title bar.  With this, I could make it appear, but it wouldn't be quite as perfect as being able to see it move up there as it collapsed.

Comment: @Kyle, You can also set animation to the `Textview` of green block in such a way that look like its moving from position x to y. Do you want me to show that ?

Comment: @Kyle mate did you get the solution for this? can you give me some advice or some code to do that?

Comment: @porya74 Hey.  Sorry this was quite a while ago and I don't actually work at the same place anymore so I'd have to do some trial to figure it out again.  If I have time I'll give it a shot.  I do remember that I ended up doing something very similar to what Dipali suggested in the comment above, not the full answer.  I used a custom behavior to actually change the position of the textview in combination with the scroll offset so they moved 1 to 1.  Once I got it into the perfect position, I set the textview to gone and set the title text.  Behavior was all work/logic

Answer (score 5):

You have to make TextView inside toolbar and set gravity as you want. for your problem it is not necessary to take toolbar, you can also use layout. This is my coordinate layout. In which you can easily adjust TextView inside toolbar.

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
tools:context="com.sashwati.metrimonial.activity.MainActivity">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
    app:elevation="0dp">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="@drawable/gradientcolor"
        app:layout_collapseMode="pin"
        app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay">
        <!-- app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"-->
        <com.sashwati.metrimonial.utils.CustomFontTextView
            android:id="@+id/toolbar_title"
            style="@style/TextAppearance.AppCompat.Widget.ActionBar.Title"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="center"
            android:text="Dhakar Matrimonial"
            android:textColor="@android:color/white"
            android:textSize="@dimen/middium_text_size"
            app:fontName="raleway_regular" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_chat"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:layout_marginRight="@dimen/middium_padding"
            android:padding="@dimen/small_padding"
            android:src="@android:drawable/stat_notify_chat" />

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/iv_universerch"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_gravity="right"
            android:padding="@dimen/small_padding"
            android:src="@mipmap/search" />

    </android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<include layout="@layout/content_main" />
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to write a custom behavior for each element you want to move, resize, hide and etc...

just create a class that extends from `CoordinatorLayout.Behavior<View>` and implement what do you want, finally set widget app:layout_behavior to the custom behavior you wrote.

See my source code on git hub [CoordinatorBehavior](https://github.com/FarshidABZ/CoordinatorBehavior)

And for more information see this GitHub project [saulmm CoordinatorExamples](https://github.com/saulmm/CoordinatorExamples)